# How to print today's date in excel in certain format

Tags: excel, date

I want to show 'Today's Date' in excel in this below format:-

**Example:** 12 March 2019

While I am trying TODAY() function it returns '3/12/2019'

Answer (score 0):

You can use Today() function and right click on the specific cell you want to format and select the **Format Cells** option. In the Format Cells box, click the **Number** tab. In the Category list, click **Date**. Select the required date format from the list of formats. You could also use the **Custom** option to specify other fomats.